# LWJGL GLSL Uniform Block Not Working

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I've looked at a number of tutorials and example programs, but I still can't seem to figure out what the problem is with my uniform blocks. I am trying to render some models using a viewMatrix, and it worked fine when it was outside of a uniform block, but moving the uniform variable into a block caused the cube to be completely transparent. (It seems to still be affecting the depth test as normal, though.)

As an overview, right now I create a UBO, bind the UBO to a preselected binding point, then do the same to the uniform block.

Here is the relevant code:

Initialization:

```
Loader loader = new Loader();
Camera camera = new Camera();
MasterRenderer renderer = new MasterRenderer(loader);
renderer.prepareCameraUBO(camera, loader);
```

Relevant Loader Code:

```
public int createUBO(int floatCount) {
    //Generate UBO
    System.out.println("Generating UBO.");
    int ubo = GL15.glGenBuffers();

    //Resize it and then unbind it
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    GL15.glBufferData(ubo, floatCount * 4, GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);       
    return ubo;
}

public void bindUBOToPoint(int uboID, int bindingPoint) {
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboID);
    GL30.glBindBufferBase(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bindingPoint, uboID);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void updateUBOData(int ubo, int offset, float[] data) {
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    GL15.glBufferSubData(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, offset, storeDataInBuffer(data));
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Relevant Camera Code:

```
public void move(Player player, Loader loader) {
    //We follow the player around and calculate the view matrix
    updateViewMatrixUBO(loader);
}

public void updateViewMatrixUBO(Loader loader) {
    loader.updateUBOData(uboID, 0, VC.convertMatrixToFloatArray(viewMatrix));
}
```

Relevant MasterRenderer Code:

```
public MasterRenderer(Loader loader) {
    enableCulling();
    createProjectionMatrix();

    entityShader = new EntityShader();
    terrainShader = new TerrainShader();

    entityRenderer = new EntityRenderer(entityShader, projectionMatrix, loader);
    terrainRenderer = new TerrainRenderer(terrainShader, projectionMatrix);
}

public void prepareCameraUBO(Camera camera, Loader loader) {
    //Create a UBO for the camera matrices.     
    int bindingPoint = 0;
    int cameraUBO = loader.createUBO(16);

    loader.bindUBOToPoint(cameraUBO, bindingPoint);

    camera.setUBOID(cameraUBO);

    entityShader.bindUniformBlockToPoint(cameraUBO, bindingPoint, "Camera");
    terrainShader.bindUniformBlockToPoint(cameraUBO, bindingPoint, "Camera");
}
```

Relevant Shader Program (Java) Code:

```
public void bindUniformBlockToPoint(int bindingPoint, String blockName) {
    GL20.glUseProgram(programID);
    GL31.glUniformBlockBinding(programID, GL31.glGetUniformBlockIndex(programID, blockName), bindingPoint);
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Relevant Shader (GLSL) Code:

```
layout (std140, row_major) uniform Camera {
    mat4 viewMatrix;
};
```

Comment: Are you're actually using row major matrix layout? How did your original `glUniformMatrix()` call look?

Comment: I used matrix.store(matrixBuffer), flipped it, and then called glUniformMatrix(). Removing row_major didn't do anything, though.